# Breeze Angular Service Not Configuring Breeze to Angular Promises

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I cannot get the Breeze Angular service (http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/breeze-angular) to configure Breeze to use Angular promises, i.e., I can never get the useNgPromises() function within breeze.bridge.angular.js to log a message to the console and thus I assume Breeze is never configured to use Angular promises.

My JS files are loaded as follows:

1. angular.js (v 1.3.14)
2. angular-route.js (v.1.3.14)
3. q.js (v 1.1.2) - This is here because I kept getting errors that Q was undefined if I left this out. I don't know if it is necessary to load Q.js if I use Angular promises instead.
4. breeze.js (v 1.5.3)
5. breeze.bridge.angular.js (v 1.1.0)
6. app.js and other app-specific JS files

So far, that satisfies steps #1 and #2 from the "Install It" section of that Breeze page.

Per steps #3 and #4 on that Breeze page and comments in breeze.bridge.angular.js, this is what my app.js looks like:

```
    window.myApp = angular.module("myApp", [
        "breeze.angular"
    ])
    .value("breeze", window.breeze)
    .config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {
        // Routing code
    }])
    .run(['breeze', function (breeze) {}]);
```

As far as I can tell, that code matches the Example #1 code on that Breeze page and satisfies steps #3 and #4 on that Breeze page.

Then I have some basic views that use controllers and datacontext JS files, the latter of which inject the breeze object as a dependency. To test whether Breeze is actually executing the configuration to work with Angular promises, I edited the breeze.bridge.angular.js file such that the following statement is included as the first line in the useNgPromises() function:

```
    console.log("Using Angular promises!");
```

When I run my app, I never see that in the console, so I assume the configuration is not happening.

Am I doing something wrong in the setup? If so, what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You absolutely do NOT need *Q.js***; the fact that you see errors relating to that library is an indication of a configuration mistake.

I think you found the problem when you added `.value("breeze", window.breeze)`.

That one line wipes out the definition of the `breeze` service established by the 'breeze.angular' module (defined in *breeze.bridge.angular.js*), thus preventing the configuration of breeze for `$http` and `$q`. Without that configuration, breeze looks for a promises implementation elsewhere ... hence the complaint about missing *Q.js*.  So ... yes ... that line was a disaster.

I *wondered* where you got the idea for that line. Thanks for referencing the Microsoft ASP Breeze/Angular template documentation. Wow that is old (2013). I'd kill it ... and the other defunct Visual Studio Breeze templates ... if I could (maybe I can). I thought we had made them hard to find. Looks like you found them. How?

That certainly isn't how we teach Breeze + Angular these days.

The ["Todo Angular" sample](http://www.getbreezenow.com/samples/todo-angular) is a far better guide (even if it is a year old).

Comment: Thank you Ward! I will refer to that sample instead going forward. You are correct about not needing Q.js. After I removed the troublesome line of code, I also stopped included Q.js and did not receive any errors. Regarding the ASP.NET Breeze/Angular template, it is not at all hard to find. It is featured along with various other templates on the main ASP.NET SPA site (http://www.asp.net/single-page-application). Unfortunately, all of the other templates they include are old as well, dated 2013.

Comment: What can I say? I wish they'd take that site down.

Comment: Would you please mark my answer as THE answer so that no one thinks there is an open issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by commenting out the line:

```
    .value("breeze", window.breeze)
```

I had included that line per the "Dependency Injection" section here: http://www.getbreezenow.com/ng-spa-template#module as well as the "Value Recipe" section here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers, but apparently it does not play well with the Breeze Angular service.

I am not sure exactly why this is the case but my best guess is that the issue was caused by Angular values not being configurable, per this explanation: https://gist.github.com/demisx/9605099, and I assume the Breeze Angular service requires the Breeze object to be configurable and therefore it should not be injected as a dependency for the app via the value recipe.

I should also note that after removing that troublesome line of code, I no longer receive an error indicating that Q.js is required since the Breeze Angular service successfully configures Breeze to use Angular's $q instead.